# Correct HAR format for sendHarRequest

Tags: owasp, zap

I am trying to test the sendHarRequest function via the locally provided OWASP ZAP API in order to send a POST Request through ZAP.

I have already tried to encode my request with the ZAP Encoder into other formats, however that wasn't successful either.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "http://service.com/questions/depot?include-backend-answers=false",
    "cookies": [],
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Accept",
        "value": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
      }
    ],
    "queryString": [
      {
        "name": "include-backend-answers",
        "value": "true"
      }
    ],
    "postData": {
      "mimeType": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "params": [],
      "text": "{\"answerQuestionWrappers\":[{\"questionId\":\"QUESTION_BENEFICIARY\",\"answers\":[{\"optionId\":\"BENEFICIARY_OPTION_1\",\"value\":1}]},{\"questionId\":\"QUESTION_PENSION_PLAN\",\"answers\":[{\"optionId\":\"PENSION_PLAN_OPTION_1\",\"value\":1}]},{\"questionId\":\"QUESTION_PENSION_INFO\",\"answers\":[{\"optionId\":\"PENSION_INFO_OPTION_1\",\"groupId\":null,\"followUp\":null,\"followUpContainsCheckbox\":null,\"followUpOnly\":null,\"value\":1}]}]}"
    }
}
```

I keep getting {"code":"illegal_parameter","message":"Provided parameter has illegal or unrecognized value"} as the response.

On the other hand using the following code within the Request Editor of ZAP works perfectly fine.

```
POST http://http://service.com/questions/depot?include-backend-answers=false HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 207
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer someAuthorizationKey
Host: service.de:12089

{"answerQuestionWrappers":[{"questionId":"QUESTION_BENEFICIARY","answers":[{"optionId":"BENEFICIARY_OPTION_1","groupId":null,"followUp":null,"followUpContainsCheckbox":null,"followUpOnly":null,"value":1}]}]}
```

I found this post in the OWASP ZAP User-Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zaproxy-users/vNfAfWvrCQ0/a73geZ8NBQAJ;context-place=forum/zaproxy-users 
and I think I have the same problem, however for me there was no clear solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can browse the API Web UI by pointing your browser at ZAP's IP:Port, ex: http://localhost:8080/ (by default).

The `sendHarRequest (request* followRedirects )` endpoint is described as:

> Sends the first HAR request entry, optionally following redirections.
>   Returns, in HAR format, the request sent and response received and
>   followed redirections, if any. The Mode is enforced when sending the
>   request (and following redirections), custom manual requests are not
>   allowed in 'Safe' mode nor in 'Protected' mode if out of scope.

For a description of Http ARchive format refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)

To get valid examples you can export them from ZAP, via the following API endpoints:

- `messageHar (id* )` - Gets the message with the given ID in HAR format
- `messagesHar (baseurl start count )` - Gets the HTTP messages sent through/by ZAP, in HAR format, optionally filtered by URL and paginated with 'start' position and 'count' of messages
- `messagesHarById (ids* )` - Gets the HTTP messages with the given IDs, in HAR format.

If you're sending post data, it'll need to be properly URL encoded.

Quote [chau362](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10223342/chau362):

> The actual problem was that I was missing the required keys "headersSize" and "bodySize" which can be set to a default of -1 if unknown, and "httpVersion", with the value "http/1.1".

As follows:

```
"request" : {
        "method" : "POST",
        "url" : "http://service.com/questions/depot?include-backend-answers=false",
        "httpVersion" : "HTTP/1.1",
        "cookies" : [ ],
        "headers" : [
      {
        "name": "Accept",
        "value": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
      }
    ],
        "queryString" : [
      {
        "name": "include-backend-answers",
        "value": "true"
      }
    ],
    "postData": {
      "mimeType": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "params": [],
      "text": "{\"answerQuestionWrappers\":[{\"questionId\":\"QUESTION_BENEFICIARY\",\"answers\":[{\"optionId\":\"BENEFICIARY_OPTION_1\",\"value\":1}]},{\"questionId\":\"QUESTION_PENSION_PLAN\",\"answers\":[{\"optionId\":\"PENSION_PLAN_OPTION_1\",\"value\":1}]},{\"questionId\":\"QUESTION_PENSION_INFO\",\"answers\":[{\"optionId\":\"PENSION_INFO_OPTION_1\",\"groupId\":null,\"followUp\":null,\"followUpContainsCheckbox\":null,\"followUpOnly\":null,\"value\":1}]}]}"
    }
    "headersSize" : -1,
    "bodySize" : -1
    },
```

Comment: I have been using the API Web UI you have mentioned. In order to clarify my problem I should have mentioned that I am not using the Spider. I am only trying to actively scan a number of predefined URLs. I am aware that if I want to scan a specific URL they have to be previously requested via ZAP, which is what I try to solve by passing a list of requests in HAR format. For GET requests this procedure works fine. Thats why I was thinking that the cause of my problem lays in the encoding of my postData.

Comment: As I said "If you're sending post data, it'll need to be properly URL encoded." If you proxy a POST through ZAP and then export the relevant HAR you'll have an example you can leverage/compare against.

Comment: The actual problem was that I was missing the required keys "headersSize" and "bodySize" which can be set to a default of -1 if unknown. In case somone has a smiliar problem here is the link for the User Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/kHyyat5xW_M Thanks anyway @kingthorin.

Comment: Perfect! Added those details to the answer.